# Replacement for UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

We are using spring security oauth2 to obtain token using client credentials grant type. We are not using the `application.properties` file for specifying the client credentials, instead we are supplying them programmatically.

```java
ClientRegistration clientRegistration = ClientRegistration
        .withRegistrationId("test")
        .clientId("testclientid")
        .clientSecret("testclientsecret")
        .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
        .tokenUri("http://test.tokenuri.com")
        .build();

ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository reactiveClientRegistrationRepository = new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistration);
ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth =
        new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
                reactiveClientRegistrationRepository,
                new UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository());
oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("test");

this.webClient = webClientFactory.getBuilder()
        .filter(oauth)
        .build();
```

The code is working fine, but we see a warning that `UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` is deprecated.
The api docs for `UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` recommend to use `AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` instead, but `AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` does not implement the same interface as `UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`. What is the recommendation on replacing the deprecated `UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` in this case?

I found https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8016 but the issue does not give much detail.

Answer (score 10):

With the help of @Jokers answer, I managed to solve this problem in the following way. I put the credentials in `appliction.properties` and seperated the RegistrationRepository for that.

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client.ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.AuthorizationGrantType;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

@Configuration
public class MyClientRequestConfig {

    @Bean
    ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository getRegistration(
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.myprovider.token-uri}") String token_uri,
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myprovider.client-id}") String client_id,
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myprovider.client-secret}") String client_secret
    ) {
        ClientRegistration registration = ClientRegistration
                .withRegistrationId("myprovider")
                .tokenUri(token_uri)
                .clientId(client_id)
                .clientSecret(client_secret)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .build();
        return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(registration);
    }

    @Bean(name = "myprovider")
    WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations) {
        InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService = new InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrations);
        AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrations, clientService);
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("myprovider");
        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(oauth)
                .build();

    }
}
```

Comment: Will it also refresh the token in case it is expired ? or I have write logic for that explicitly ?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test this at the moment. But it should be easy to test if you have control over your provider you want to communicate to: Set the token timeout very low and send requests before and after timeout.

Comment: I think you need to write logic for refreshing the token

Comment: As Joker said, explicit logic is needed for refreshing

Answer (score 7):

Allthough kotlin code (conversion should be easy to java), we ended up with something like that:

```kotlin
val clientRegistryRepo = InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(ClientRegistration
    .withRegistrationId("test")
    .tokenUri("http://test.tokenuri.com")
    .clientId("testClientId")
    .clientSecret("testclientsecret")
    .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
    .build())
val clientService = InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistryRepo)
val authorizedClientManager =
    AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistryRepo, clientService)
val oauthFilter = ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager)
oauthFilter.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("test")
WebClient.builder()
        .filter(oauthFilter)
        .build()
```